# example which does not satify Lipschitz condition, but has a unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y'=1+\sqrt y\\y(0)=0 $$
>   Show that this IVP does not satisfy Lipschitz condition, but has a unique solution.

I have shown the first way, like this:
Let $f(x,y)=1+\sqrt y $. Then $\frac {|f(x,y_1)-f(x,0)|}{|y_1-0|}=|\frac{1}{\sqrt y_1}| \rightarrow \infty $ as $y_1\rightarrow 0 $. How to show the uniqueness part?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can solve this separable equation to get the general solution (in the implicit form: $x$ a function of $y$).  There is only one value of the constant
that makes $x \to 0$ as $y \to 0+$.

EDIT: $$\int \dfrac{dy}{1+\sqrt{y}} = 2 \sqrt{y} - 2 \ln(1+ \sqrt{y}) + C$$

EDIT: More generally, for $y' = f(y)$ where $f$ is continuous and positive for $y \ge 0$ you have the implicit solutions $x = F(y) + c$ where $F(y) = \displaystyle\int_0^y \dfrac{ds}{f(s)}$, and these solution curves never intersect.

Comment: You need the fact that $1+\sqrt{y}>0$ in order to do this in the first place. It would work with $y'=\sqrt{y}$ except for the issue of division by zero.

Comment: ok I did the integration, $\int \frac{dy}{1+\sqrt y}$ which looks a big value, can you please write the full solution, or take a snapshot and paste it here?